# Commerce Billy: adding new textarea in form

Tags: commerce, forms

To add an new textarea ('invoice_special') for input on admin form of module [commerce_billy](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_billy), I copied the below code from *commerce_billy_pdf.admin.inc* into a custom module, but the new form field does not appear. If I edit file *commerce_billy_pdf.admin.inc* directly, the field appears. What I am doing wrong here?

```
    function commerce_billy_pdf_admin_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $settings = variable_get('commerce_billy_pdf_text_settings', array());

  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_settings'] = array(
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('PDF Text settings'),
  );

  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_settings']['invoice_header'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Invoice header'),
    '#default_value' => isset($settings['invoice_header']) ? $settings['invoice_header'] : '',
  );
  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_settings']['invoice_location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Location'),
    '#default_value' => isset($settings['invoice_location']) ? $settings['invoice_location'] : '',
  );
  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_settings']['invoice_date_format'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Date format'),
    '#default_value' => isset($settings['invoice_date_format']) ? $settings['invoice_date_format'] : 'Y-m-d',
  );
  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_settings']['invoice_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Invoice text'),
    '#default_value' => isset($settings['invoice_text']) ? $settings['invoice_text'] : '',
  );
  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_settings']['invoice_footer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Invoice footer'),
    '#default_value' => isset($settings['invoice_footer']) ? $settings['invoice_footer'] : '',
  );

  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_settings']['invoice_special'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Invoice special'),
    '#default_value' => isset($settings['invoice_special']) ? $settings['invoice_special'] : '',
  );

  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_logo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Logo'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('commerce_billy_pdf_logo', 'misc/druplicon.png'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Path to invoice logo.'),
  );

  $css_files = variable_get('commerce_billy_pdf_css_files', array(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_billy_pdf') . '/css/pdf.css'));
  $default_value = "";
  foreach ($css_files as $file) {
    $default_value .= $file . "\n";
  }
  $form['commerce_billy_pdf_css_files'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Inline CSS files'),
    '#default_value' => $default_value,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('One CSS file per line.'),
  );

  $form = system_settings_form($form);
  // Use custom submit handler.
  $form['#submit'] = array('commerce_billy_pdf_admin_form_submit');
  return $form;
}
```